# Hide application window in C

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++

I know how to hide the window of console app in C# by this code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//Insert below before the main function
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;

///End of before main


//now insert this under main function


var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

// Hide
ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

// Show
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
```

Now the problem is , how to hide the window in C, not C++ ? i've searched for a solutions but all I found in C++.

Comment: Normally it would make sense not to create a window in the first place

Comment: What an odd question: You have explained how to access a C API from C#, but are now asking, how you would access the C API from C. The answer is as mundane as it is unhelpful to future visitors: Just access the C API. You are using C, so there is no intermediary required.

Comment: And yet, I have to side with David Heffernan on this one. People that need to hide the console window usually don't know understand, why that console is created in the first place, and that you can control that behavior. You should probably target `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` instead of `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`, and the system won't allocate a console for you.

Comment: For .net, go to application settings, you will see "outputtype: Console Application", change that to "Windows Application" if you don't want the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All WinAPI calls are c declarations (not c++).

So, you do just the same:

```
//don't need to declare anything just:
#include <Windows.h>

//insert this in the main function
HWND handle = GetConsoleWindow();

// Hide
ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

// Show
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
```